# How do I query for dates in Spring Data MongoDB repository?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

My domain object -

```
Person{
    String name;
    Date born;
}
```

and I have a PersonRepository

```
PersonRepository{
    @Query(value="{'born': {$gt: new Date(?0)} }")
    findPerson(Date bornAfter);
}
```

I'm trying to fetch all Persons born after a certain date. That doesn't work though. What am I missing? The date-format for 'born' in mongodb console looks like

```
ISODate("2011-11-16T09:46:33.750Z")
```

I tried to look for a unit/integration test for this in data-jpa source. Couldn't find any. Can someone point me to it?

Answer (score 12):

So first you have to make sure you don't mix up Spring Data JPA with Spring Data MongoDB here. I don't think any part of the question is actually targetting some JPA stuff. Here's how your Repository might look like:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends Repository<Person, Long> {

  // Query generated from the method name
  List<Person> findByBornGreaterThan(Date born);

  @Query("{'born' : { '$gt' : ?0 }}")
  List<Person> findPersons(Date born);
}
```

The latter does not work for 1.0.1.RELEASE and I have created a [ticket](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAMONGO-425) for that and already fixed it for the upcoming versions 1.0.2.RELEASE and 1.1.0.M1. So you might wanna grab a snapshot build to try it. I have also created a [ticket](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATACMNS-141) to add `Before` and `After` to the supported keywords for more intuitive use than `LessThan` and `GreaterThan` currently allow.

Comment: I'm sorry I referenced jpa incorrectly. I'm using spring-data mongodb. However the solution you proposed does not work. Here's the query it comes up with  { "born" : { "$gt" : "Fri Nov 18 18:05:07 PST 2011"}} which returns no results when it should have. I'm using the explicit @Query form. Furthermore, the integration tests do not have an example of testing by dates.

Comment: Good catch. I've created some tickets to capture the bug and edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Something where I have searched all the internet for and I cannot find anywhere is that the `@Aggregation` takes `Date` arguments like in this answer. Maybe useful for future developers.

Answer (score 2):

Either use the `@Query` annotation or use the key words in the method name. I'd advise to just stick with the key words in the method name. Which means this annotation can be removed. Means,
`List<Person> findByBornGreaterThan(Date born);` 
will only work. You can refer https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html for more clarification.